# Consider a Hamming(7, 4) code and the word 1111111 received at the output of a noisy binary channel

Tags: error-correcting-codes, hamming-code

Why is it possible that this word can have 4 errors but not 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message 1111111 cannot have 2 errors because 1111111 is a valid codeword and the minimum Hamming distance between any two distinct codewords of $H(7,4)$ is $3$.

To see that it can have $4$ errors, notice that 0010110 is a valid codeword.